# Making a menu driven program, errors

Tags: c

Beginner to C and doing an assignment for a course. Fixed what I think needed to be fixed, but my menu will only go to part A, but not B, C, or D. It quits fine as well. No errors, wondering what is wrong with my code.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define PAUSE system("pause")
#define CLS system("cls")
#define FLUSH flush()

// Prototype Functions Here
void highestNumber(int, int, int);
void lowestNumber(int, int, int);
void displayAverage(int, int, int);
void displayMenu();
void flush();
char getUserChoice();

main() {
    char userSelection;
    int number1 = 0, number2 = 0, number3 = 0;
    do {
        userSelection = getUserChoice(); // Gets/DisplaysMenu
        switch (userSelection) {

        case  'A': // Enter a number
            printf("Enter a number 1: ");
            scanf("%i", &number1);

            printf("Enter a number 2: ");
            scanf("%i", &number2);

            printf("Enter a number 3: ");
            scanf("%i", &number3);
            break;

        case  'B': // Display Highest Number Entered
            printf("In Case B");
            highestNumber;
            break;

        case  'C': // Display Lowest Number entered
            printf("In Case C");
            lowestNumber;
            break;

        case 'D': // Display Average of Numbers entered
            printf("In Case D");
            displayAverage;
            break;

        case  'Q': // Quit the program
            printf("You have quit the program\n");
            PAUSE;
            break;
        default: // Invalid Selection
            printf("Invalid selection...try again!\n");
            PAUSE;
            break;
        } // end switch
    } while (userSelection != 'Q');
    PAUSE;
} // end of main
  //==============

void highestNumber(int number1, int number2, int number3) {
    if (number1 > number2 && number1 > number3) {
        printf("The highest number is: %i", number1);
    }

    else if (number2 > number1 && number2 > number3) {
        printf("The highest number is: %i", number2);
    }
    else if (number3 > number2 && number3 > number1) {
        printf("The highest number is: %i", number3);
    }
} //end highest number

void lowestNumber(int number1, int number2, int number3) {
    if (number1 < number2 && number1 < number3) {
        printf("The lowest number is: %i", number1);
    }

    else if (number2 < number1 && number2 < number3) {
        printf("The lowest number is: %i", number2);
    }
    else if (number3 < number2 && number3 < number1) {
        printf("The lowest number is: %i", number3);
    } 
} // end lowest number

void displayAverage(int number1, int number2, int number3) {
    int average = (number1 + number2 + number3) / 3;
    printf("The average of the three numbers you entered is: %i", average);
} // display average

void displayMenu() {
    CLS;
    printf("\n===============================\n");
    printf("========== MAIN MENU ==========\n");
    printf("===============================\n");
    printf("A. Enter a number\n");
    printf("B. Display Highest Number entered\n");
    printf("C. Display Lowest Number entered\n");
    printf("D. Display Average of Numbers entered\n");
    printf("Q. Quit the program\n");
    printf("Enter your choice: ");
} // end displayMenu

void flush() {
    while (getchar() != '\n');
} // end flush

char getUserChoice() {
    char result;
    displayMenu();
    scanf("%c", &result); FLUSH;
    result = toupper(result);
    return result;
} // end getUserChoice
```

Comment: `enterNumber(int, int, int)` that says the function requires three parameters. `enterNumber();` that calls the function with zero parameter. See the problem? Same for the other function definitions and calls.

Comment: I see that, but what do I do? put enterNumber(int, int, int); as well under the case?

Comment: when prototyping functions that have no parameters, place `void` between the parens.  Otherwise what is actually be prototyped is a function that can have any number of parameters

Comment: Still having trouble.

Answer (score 0):

the following code should perform as you want.

Caveat: there may be some details that you would like to modify such as uncommenting the calls to `getchar()`

The following code has a number of constraints built it, like must enter the 3 numbers before trying to do any operations on those numbers.

The following code does not use non-portable calls to the shell.

the data is kept locally in the `main()` function and passed to each of the sub functions that need it.

Notice the function that changes the data is passed pointers to the data so the sub function can change that data.

useless macros were eliminated

the function: `flush()` was renamed for clarity as to what it does

appropriate error checking added

commented out unneeded `if()` statements

expanded `flushStdin()` to allow for either EOF or '\n'

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>


// Prototype Functions Here
void enterNumber   (int*, int*, int*);  // pass address so function can update

void highestNumber (int, int, int);
void lowestNumber  (int, int, int);
void displayAverage(int, int, int);

void displayMenu   ( void ); // corrected prototypes
void flushStdin    ( void );
char getUserChoice ( void );



int main( void )         // only two valid signatures for main()
                         // this is one of them
{
    char userSelection;  

    int number1;         // added local data variables
    int number2;
    int number3;

    int gotSelections = 0; // so cannot try to work with uninitialized data

    do 
    {
        userSelection = getUserChoice(); // Gets/DisplaysMenu
        switch (userSelection) 
        {

        case  '1': // Enter a number
            enterNumber( &number1, &number2, &number3 ); // pass expected parameters
            gotSelections = 1;
            break;

        case  '2': // Display Highest Number Entered
            if( gotSelections )
            { // then data initialized
                highestNumber( number1, number2, number3 ); // pass expected parameters
            }

            else
            { // else tried to pass unitialized data
                printf( "must enter numbers before gathering Statistics\n" );
            }
            break;

        case  '3': // Display Lowest Number entered
            if( gotSelections )
            { // then data initialized
                lowestNumber( number1, number2, number3 ); // pass expected parameters
            }

            else
            { // else tried to pass unitialized data
                printf( "must enter numbers before gathering Statistics\n" );
            }
            break;

        case '4': // Display Average of Numbers entered
            if( gotSelections )
            { // then data initialized
                displayAverage( number1, number2, number3 );
            }

            else
            { // else tried to pass unitialized data
                printf( "must enter numbers before gathering Statistics\n" );
            }
            break;

        case  'Q': // Quit the program
            printf("You have quit the program\n");
            //system( "pause" );
            break;

        default: // Invalid Selection
            printf("Invalid selection...try again!\n");
            //system( "pause" );
            break;
        } // end switch
        flushStdin();
        //getchar();
    } while (userSelection != 'Q');

    //system( "pause" );
    //flushStdin();
    getchar();
} // end of main


void enterNumber(int * pNumber1, int *pNumber2, int *pNumber3) 
{
    printf("Enter a number 1:\n ");
    if( 1 != scanf("%i", pNumber1) )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "scanf for number1 failed" );
        flushStdin();
        getchar();
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    printf("Enter a number 2:\n ");
    if( 1 != scanf("%i", pNumber2) ) 
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "scanf failed for number2" );
        flushStdin();
        getchar();
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    printf("Enter a number 3:\n ");
    if( 1 != scanf("%i", pNumber3) )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "scanf for number3 failed" );
        flushStdin();
        getchar();
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }
} //end enter number


void highestNumber(int number1, int number2, int number3) 
{
    if (number1 > number2 && number1 > number3) 
    {
        printf("The highest number is: %i\n", number1);
    }

    else if (number2 > number1 && number2 > number3) 
    {
        printf("The highest number is: %i\n", number2);
    }

    else //if (number3 > number2 && number3 > number1) 
    {
        printf("The highest number is: %i\n", number3);
    }
} //end highest number


void lowestNumber(int number1, int number2, int number3) 
{
    if (number1 < number2 && number1 < number3) 
    {
        printf("The lowest number is: %i\n", number1);
    }

    else if (number2 < number1 && number2 < number3) 
    {
        printf("The lowest number is: %i\n", number2);
    }

    else //if (number3 < number2 && number3 < number1) 
    {
        printf("The lowest number is: %i\n", number3);
    } 
} // end lowest number


void displayAverage(int number1, int number2, int number3) 
{
    int average = (number1 + number2 + number3) / 3;
    printf("The average of the three numbers you entered is: %i\n", average);
} // display average


void displayMenu() 
{
    //system( "cls" );  
    puts( "\033[H \033[J"); // \033 is octal value for 'escape'
    printf("\n===============================\n");
    printf("========== MAIN MENU ==========\n");
    printf("===============================\n");
    printf("1. Enter a number\n");
    printf("2. Display Highest Number entered\n");
    printf("3. Display Lowest Number entered\n");
    printf("4. Display Average of Numbers entered\n");
    printf("Q. Quit the program\n");
    printf("Enter your choice: ");
} // end displayMenu


void flushStdin() 
{
    int ch;
    while ( (ch = getchar()) != EOF && '\n' != ch );
} // end flush


char getUserChoice() 
{
    char result;

    displayMenu();

    if( 1 != scanf(" %c", &result) )
    { 
        fprintf( stderr, "scanf for menu entry failed" );
        flushStdin();
        getchar();
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    flushStdin();
    //getchar();
    result = (char)toupper((int)result);

    return result;
} // end getUserChoice
```